# Congruence question, does -1 matter?

Tags: relations, congruences

I am proving symmetry in a relation.

Assume: I have $a\,R\,b$ which is $x+y\equiv z+w\pmod 2$.
I want to show $b\,R\,a$ which would be $z +w\equiv x+y\pmod 2$.

("$x\mid y$" is the divides symbol.)

From the assumption I have $2\mid(z + w) - (x + y)$.

I want to show that $2\mid(x + y) - (z + w)$.

From the assumption can I factor out a $-1$ on top to say.... $2\mid-((x + y) - (z + w))$

and then just say a $-1$ doesn't matter in modular arithmetic? Or does it? My roommate says.. which is true that $-5\bmod 3$ isn't the same as $5 \bmod 3$.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't read the whole thing, but note that $-1\pmod {10} = 10-1\pmod {10}$.

Hence $-5 \pmod 3= 3-5 \pmod 3=-2\pmod 3 = 1 \pmod 3 \ne 5\pmod 3 = 2 \pmod 3$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $x\mid y$, the divides relation, says that there is an integer $n$ such that $y=nx$.

Then if $x\mid y$ we have $y=nx$ and $-y=(-n)x$, and $-n$ is also an integer, so $x\mid-y$.

More generally, if $k$ is an integer, then $x\mid y$ implies $x\mid ky$, and this is the special case when $k=-1$.

Comment: so it looks like the factoring out -1 and making y = -y doesnt matter! ty

Comment: @k9b I'm not sure I like the term "doesn't matter", but it is true that $x\mid y$, $-x\mid y$, $x\mid -y$, $-x\mid -y$ are all equivalent.